# Facebook Android SDK does not recognize installs

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

Facebook Android SDK receives data about the activation of the mobile app, but not about the installs. We rolled back the SDK version, checked the code 10 times - but we didnt get any result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z73cF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNiqg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fWa5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFGn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M95fq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E0uY.png)

Comment: Did you manage to fix that? Same issue here with fb_auto_published / fb_mobile_launch_source events

Comment: Was the reason that nobody installed it from the store yet?